# Unity2D - Parameter does not exist, even though I've defined it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got two parameters in my animator, one called "horizontal" and one called "vertical." *(see image below)*

[image]

The "vertical" parameter works exactly as I'd like it to, but the "horizontal" one, despite using the same code, doesn't work. Here's my code snippet (I know it's kinda inefficient, I don't need feedback on that):

```
void Update()
    {
        x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        animcon.SetInteger("horizontal", Mathf.RoundToInt(x));
        animcon.SetInteger("vertical", Mathf.RoundToInt(y));
    }
```

and my error:

```
Parameter 'horizontal' does not exist.
UnityEngine.Animator:SetInteger (string,int)
```

AFAIK no spelling errors are present, but every other question like this is based around that solution.

Comment: A colleague of mine was tearing his head out when he accidently added a space to the end of an item name. I'm not sure if Unity will trim the variable names of whitespace here, or if that might be issue? As such, maybe delete the property and add it again.

Comment: OIFHADSFHUIDSFHUISDFHIUSFDHUSFDHUFDSHIU thank you so much lmao I was about to lose my mind, you totally had it. AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a space at the end of my var name, thanks @Milan Egon Votrubec!